# Scala groupby Element type

Tags: list, scala, collections, types

I have writing a textparser which parses a given piece of text using n parsers (generated by training over n samples) which are contained a list of the type

`List(Parser1_Object, Parser2_Object, Parser1_Object, Parser3_Object,....)`

Note that each object has parameter(s)( let's say in this case all of them have the same parameter named `param`) whose value(s) may vary. My objective is to reduce the list to remove common parsers (i.e. objects with same parameters) for further processing and use. To achieve the same I was thinking of grouping the elements of the same type and then work on reducing each of these groups. However I am unsure on how to `groupBy` with types. Any suggestions/pointers on the same would be helpful (Or if there is a better functional way to approach the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `getClass` to group objects by runtime type:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, "1", "2", 2.0, 3.0)
l: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 1, 2, 2.0, 3.0)

scala> l.groupBy(_.getClass)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Class[_],List[Any]] = 
   Map(class java.lang.String -> List(1, 2), 
       class java.lang.Double -> List(2.0, 3.0), 
       class java.lang.Integer -> List(1, 2))
```

You may also want to wrap it into `scala.reflect.ClassTag`, like `l.groupBy(x => ClassTag(x.getClass))`.

Comment: Alright, thanks, _.getclass did the trick, but I could not use the type information further to work on each of these groups with pattern matching (got a warning for type erasure) - I guess the ClassTag and TypeTag can be used for the same (need to read up on this). Just a minor question on the above, is ```ClassTag(x.getClass).tpe``` correct? I don't see tpe value members for Classtag @ http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag

Comment: @Ark Oops, I was experimenting with `TypeTag`s in parallel, `tpe` is correct only for them. Fixed the answer. Thanks!